# error cannot convert string TO uint_8t

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, home-automation

this is the code i am working on for controlling leds

```
#include <WiFi.h>                                                // esp32 library
#include <IOXhop_FirebaseESP32.h>                                             // firebase library
#define FIREBASE_HOST "mmmmm"                         // the project name address from firebase id
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "mmmmmmm"                    // the secret key generated from firebase
#define WIFI_SSID "mmmmm"                                          // input your home or public wifi name
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "mmmmmm"                                    //password of wifi ssid

String fireStatus ; 
String fireStatus1 ; 
String fireStatus3 ; 
String fireStatus4 ; // led status received from firebase
int relay1 = 15;
int relay2 = 2;
int relay3 = 4;
int relay4 = 5; 

void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);

pinMode(15, OUTPUT);
pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);                
WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);                                      //try to connect with wifi
Serial.print("Connecting to ");
Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);
  Serial.print("IP Address is : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());                                                      //print local IP address
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);                                       // connect to firebase

}
void loop() {

  {
    fireStatus =  Firebase.getString("S1");

    Serial.println("Switch1 Turned ON/OFF");                 
    digitalWrite(15,fireStatus );
    fireStatus1 =  Firebase.getString("S2");
     Serial.println("Switch2 Turned ON/OFF");                 
    digitalWrite(2,fireStatus1 );


     fireStatus3 =  Firebase.getString("S3");
     Serial.println("Switch3 Turned ON/OFF");                 
    digitalWrite(4,fireStatus3));


     fireStatus4 =  Firebase.getString("S4");

     Serial.println("Switch4 Turned ON/OFF");                 
    digitalWrite(5,fireStatus4 );

}
}
```

Comment: You should always provide the full error message including the line, where the error occurred

Comment: You cannot directly cast a String to an uint8 for use with `digitalWrite()`. What string do you get from Firebase?

Comment: `fireStatus.toInt()` or `Firebase.getInt("S1")`?